# Getting NO2 concentrations for a given area

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, remote-sensing, sentinel-5p, air-quality

I am trying to get the NO2 concentrations at different coordinates for a specified area.

From the nc file downloaded from sci hub copernicus, I extracted the latitude, longitude and the NO2 concentration for every point and stored them in a csv file, with different columns for each. Here's the code:

```
import os
import netCDF4 as nc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

data_dir = "/5p_data"

data = {
    "Date": [],
    "Time": [],
    "Latitude": [],
    "Longitude": [],
    "NO2 Concentration": []
}

for file in os.listdir(data_dir):
    if file.endswith(".nc"):
        with nc.Dataset(os.path.join(data_dir, file)) as dataset:
            group_path = dataset.groups['PRODUCT']
            time = group_path.variables['time'][0].item()
            date_and_time = datetime(2010, 1, 1) + timedelta(seconds=time)

            latitude = np.squeeze(group_path.variables['latitude'][:]).flatten()
            longitude = np.squeeze(group_path.variables['longitude'][:]).flatten()
            
            # Check if 'nitrogendioxide_tropospheric_column' exists in variables
            if 'nitrogendioxide_tropospheric_column' not in group_path.variables:
                continue

            no2_concentration = np.squeeze(group_path.variables['nitrogendioxide_tropospheric_column'][:]).flatten()
            
            num_rows = latitude.size

            data["Date"].extend([date_and_time.date()] * num_rows)
            data["Time"].extend([date_and_time.time()] * num_rows)
            data["Latitude"].extend(latitude)
            data["Longitude"].extend(longitude)
            data["NO2 Concentration"].extend(no2_concentration)

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv("output/no2_data.csv", index=False)
```

The problem is that the latitude, longitude value pairs I am getting are outside the specified area. The metadata provides the correct values for lat min, lat max, lon min and lon max.
Here's a snip of that:

[image]

Any idea why this might be happening? Is getting the concentrations at every  point even possible?

I even downloaded the data for a different area farther away from the one I was previously testing to see if there was a problem with that specific region and faced the same problem, only very few points are within the selected area. Could there be a problem with how I'm storing the data, but then if I choose a range of 73.3-73.7 for longitude or latitude, I get values in 60s and 80s as well.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. Please help us to help you by providing more details on your procedure to make it reproducible. Example data might also be useful, and would a plot or screen capture of your result.